# AFNetworking Download & save data when request is successful only

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

In my iOS Application I am using `AFNetworking` library to manage required HTTP operations.

I have created a method to download a file:

```
+ (void)downloadFile:(File *)file progress:(void (^)(NSUInteger receivedBytes, long long totalReceivedBytes, long long totalExpectedBytes))progress success:(void (^)())success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:file.url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[FCFileManager pathForTemporaryDirectoryWithPath:file.key.lastPathComponent] append:NO];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
    {
        progress(bytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        success();
    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        failure(error);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Although, there is a problem with this method. If the download is canceled in progress (force quit), the file still could be found in application directory. How to create a file download, to save a file to documents directory when download is finished successfully only?

Comment: maybe in completionBlock you can catch the operation.error. if is nil, the download finished well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the download saves the file in a temporary file location and then in the completion block copy the resulting temp file to a "live" location. When the app starts up, any data in the temporary location can be considered incomplete and deleted

Comment: This sounds like a work around... Maybe there is a better way to handle a download operation?

Comment: You only other option is no to write the file to disk while it is downloading but keep it in memory. This does mean that when downloading large files you will be using up all the devices its memory. The suggestion by @flaxicode is very widely used and generally accepted as a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using [NSUrlSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithResumeData:completionHandler:) from the Foundation framework itself will handle the failed download by yourself:

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithResumeData:(NSData *)resumeData
                                   completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL *location,
                                                               NSURLResponse *response,
                                                               NSError *error))completionHandler
```

> You should pass a nil completion handler only when creating tasks in
>   sessions whose delegates include a
>   URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL: method.
>
> Your app can obtain a resumeData object in two ways:
>
> - If your app cancels an existing transfer by calling
>     cancelByProducingResumeData:, the session object passes a resumeData
>     object to the completion handler that you provided in that call.
> - If a transfer fails, the session object provides an NSError object
>     either to its delegate or to the task’s completion handler. In that
>     object, the NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData key in the userInfo
>     dictionary contains a resumeData object.
>
> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume
>   method.
>
> If the request completes successfully, the location parameter of the
>   completion handler block contains the location of the temporary file,
>   and the error parameter is nil. If the request fails, the location
>   parameter is nil and the error parameter contain information about the
>   failure.

If you want to use AFNetworking for that, it should be fully compatible since it has `AFURLSessionManager` to handle `NSUrlSession`.

Comment: Are you talking about downloading according to example: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking?

Comment: I'm talking about file downloads in general, as I said Apple already handles what you need in their framework without creating temporary files. The documentation is quite clear about it.